# java.io.IOException: Too many open files from akka.actor.internal-dispatcher

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have a REST API written in Scala with Play framework and Akka, deployed on the production server. Periodically the container with the API crashes with the following error:

```
[ERROR] [01/18/2023 13:14:02.762] [application-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-3] [akka://application/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Accept error: could not accept new connection
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:533)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:285)
        at akka.io.TcpListener.acceptAllPending(TcpListener.scala:128)
        at akka.io.TcpListener$$anonfun$bound$1.applyOrElse(TcpListener.scala:96)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.io.TcpListener.aroundReceive(TcpListener.scala:36)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

I have tried to increase a `ulimit`. It is now set to 1000000, didn't help at all. I assume it is connected to the amount of TCP connections but I cannot pinpoint the exact cause, nor can I reproduce it on my machine.

Would greatly appreciate any tips on how to handle this.

Comment: What exactly did you do to increase ulimit?

Comment: Modified limits.conf, set both hard and soft for * and root to 1000000

Comment: Maybe something overrides it? Like the server start up script or bashrc or something?

Comment: I checked it with ulimit -n and it shows correct numbers.  So I don't think that's the case. It is an Azure VM so it's slightly different from the simple server machines I guess, but there is no start up scripts or anything, it should be up and running permanently.

Comment: Settings are per process, not sure what "checking with ulimit" would tell you ... VM itself might be overriding :/ Any way you can switch to Hotspot?

Comment: I believe with limits.conf the settings should be applied globally. I am not an administrator for the Azure machine, I can ask the person responsible about it. No, there is no other options. But let's say it is not a ulimit, any thoughts of what else could be the reason ?

Comment: It is applied globally, but can be overridden per process. It's gotta be ulimit ... Unless you are leaking connections. That's also a possibility I suppose.

Comment: I see, I will discuss this with the administrator of the Azure machine, maybe he knows more about the limit for tcp connections. Just in case, is there a way to debug the leakage of connections? As I mentioned, I failed to reproduce this on my machine running test deployment and I am not quite familiar with akka, unfortunately.